# How to make values in row appear as NULL if they are not in other table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

I have two tables. First is `movie` which has `mID`, `title`. Second is `rating` which has `rID`, `mID`, `stars`, `ratingDate`. (mID standing for movieID).

Not all mID's from movie are in rating.

I would like a query that presents a table with columns rID, title, stars, ratingDate. And to show `NULL` values for ratingDate, Stars, rID, where movie.mID is not in rating.mID.

The closest I got to a real table was;

```
    SELECT distinct rID, title, stars, ratingDate
    FROM rating, movie
    WHERE movie.mID = rating.mID;
```

The reason I omitted the rows that I wanted to have NULL values, is that when I left that statement out I received a table with 112 rows, which is incorrect. There should be 16 rows in the set.
(note: 14 rows when this query is made).

Comment: I think you need to learn `OUTER JOIN`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join`.  Also, I don't think you need the `distinct`:

```
SELECT rID, title, stars, ratingDate
FROM movie m left join
     rating
     on m.mID = r.mID;
```

You should learn to use modern `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use `,` in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work. I will go look at the documentation for 'left join' and join syntax.
Also, is there a reason why not to use a comma in the from clause?

Comment: It is a very old style syntax, replaced by `join` in the ANSI 1992 standard.  The syntax does not support outer joins, which are very useful.  Better to just use the better syntax that is more powerful.

Comment: Absolutely please do use ANSI join syntax! and the simple rule is a great way to avoid the old habit. (@Gordon Linoff outer joins were possible in that old syntax they were just horrid; and accidental cross joins more frequent :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to do an Outer Join on your data, that will return what you want. As stated on an earlier answer. But I suggest reading this site for understaing joins in a more visual representation that will show you how to do joins well and the data you expect Pie charts and all: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

And I also agree, distinct is not really needed once you start joining.

Comment: Thank you, I quickly skimmed the site you provided and have bookmarked it for study later today.

Comment: Lol I was looking for a similar resource. not too great with SQL myself so Win-Win!